# Google_api credentials error from CMD or.bat file execution but not from IDEs

Tags: python, cmd, google-api

I have a python script that runs fine when I compile it from Spyder or Jupyter Notebook or whateverIDE or Visual Studio; however when I try to run it from command prompt I get the following error.

> line 50, in func_get_credentials_ret_service
>       if not creds or not creds.valid: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'creds' referenced before assignment

I have tried blocking out certain parts of the get credentials code etc. but I think for pretty obvious reasons this is not a solution.

Does not work if I run as a command in .bat file either (gives the same error)

Thank you in advance for any help that can be provided.
Below are the relevant code sections

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from Message_list import ListMessagesMatchingQuery
from dateutil import parser
import datetime as dt
import pprint
import sys
import base64
from apiclient import errors
import pandas as pd
import holidays

def func_get_credentials_ret_service():
    ##########################################################################
    ## From google api page
    ##
    ##########################################################################
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    return service

service = func_get_credentials_ret_service()
results = ListMessagesMatchingQuery(service, "me", 'from: "someprovider.com"')
id_list = func_create_id_list(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You are making a comparison on the variable `creds` before you have assigned it a value.*

#### Fix:

The line:

```py
if not creds or not creds.valid:
```

will execute if your `token.pickle` file exists, however there is no assignment of the variable `creds` before this is called.

Add this line after the definition of `SCOPES`:

```py
creds = None
```

Comment: You need to run the python command from inside the directory that contains the `.py` file. Use `cd` to change to the directory and then run `python Get_portfolio_from_vpm_set_up_cramer_trades.py`.

Comment: Okay no worries! This is a different error so I tihnk it would be best asked as a new question. If you could please accept this answer as it solved the error in the original question and ask a new question with all the relevant details that would be really helpful for the community - it's best to keep comments on-topic and it is difficult to debug errors through comments.

Comment: What worked is to change the dir . The creds = None  line ends up creating an issue. THANK YOU. 
For anyone that cares: If you have a bat file that works for executing your python script just add: cd "path to credentials file" to the first line of your bat file and it should work. Rafa thanks again.

Comment: `local variable 'creds' referenced before assignment` got resolved by adding the `creds = None` line, changing the directory was an additional thing that needed to be done after this error was resolved. The `creds = None` line is [in the original Google Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample).